# Render once on "simultaneous" attribute change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

In my Backbone.js app, I have the following Model and View:

```
var Operation = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function() {
        return {
            sign: '-',
            value: '0000',
            index: 0
        }
    }
});
var operation = new Operation();

var OperationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#operation',

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:sign change:value', this.renderOperation);
        this.renderOperation();
    },

    renderOperation: function() {
        console.log('rendered once');
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('sign') + this.model.get('value'));
    }
});
var operationView = new OperationView({ model: operation });
```

Where the view watches for

```
'change:sign change:value'
```

(...updating the view whenever "sign" or "value" change.)

When I use

```
// Test
setInterval(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt(operation.get('value'), 10);
    newValue += 500;
    newValue += '';
    operation.set({ 'sign': '+', 'value': newValue });
}, 1000);
```

...the first time the setInterval executes, the view updates twice ("rendered once" is console.logged 2 times).

However, since I am setting both sign and value "simultaneously", I would rather if my view only updated once.

Question: In Backbone.js, is there any way to listenTo() changes in multiple (specific) attributes of a model, and only render the view *once* if said multiple attributes are set simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You view is listening to both `'change:sign change:value',`

So when ever there is a change in that attribute, the event triggers once for each attribute change.

You can always listen to the `change` event on the model. which will trigger only a single `change` if the model properties are changed in the same set hash.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.renderOperation);
```

**[Check Fiddle - Change Event](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zTvYM/3/)**

But if you still want to listen to multiple change events on attributes and which fires the event only once. You might resort to a hack to passing `{silent: true}` when setting the value , and triggering attribute change event. It's a bit hacky.

```
var Operation = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function () {
        return {
            sign: '-',
            value: '0000',
            index: 0
        }
    }
});
var operation = new Operation();

var OperationView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#operation',

    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:sign change:value', this.renderOperation);
        this.renderOperation();
    },

    renderOperation: function () {
        console.log('rendered once');
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('sign') + this.model.get('value'));
    }
});
var operationView = new OperationView({
    model: operation
});

setInterval(function() {
    var newValue = parseInt(operation.get('value'), 10);
    newValue += 500;
    newValue += '';
    operation.set({ 'sign': '+', 'value': newValue }, {silent: true});
    operation.trigger('change:sign')
}, 1000);
```

**[Suppress events and trigger Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/zTvYM/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this does not answer my question. I want to listen to "changes in multiple (specific) attributes of a model". In your example, my view would update when ANY attribute changes, but I do not want to update my view when my "index" attribute changes.

Comment: You can always pass `silent:true` property whenever you set  the index on the model.. So it won't trigger the change event. Otherwise you can go with option 2 that I provided that is triggering the events after setting the property but listening to `'change:sign change:value',` change events on specific attributes

Comment: Ah, I see. Good edit, that answers my question exactly. The solution isn't pretty, but that's to be expected given the rather persnickety scenario I've set up. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Jackson.. Glad to have helped :)